# Unusual resistor symbol: resitor with Z overlaid

Tags: resistors, symbol

I found this symbol in a vendor circuit diagram. What does it mean? It looks like they are trying to convey some sort of limiting.

It's a resistor symbol with a line over the top that has both the top and bottom ends flattened.

[image: unusual resistor symbol]

Comment: It appears to be a varistor (voltage-dependent resistor). Not sure if a duplicate, so I'm posting this as a comment.

Comment: It is indeed the IEEE symbol for a Varistor. The IEC symbol is a square box with the same line through it. Source: http://www.electronicshub.org/varistor/

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi No, a variable resistor has a different symbol - it is a diagonal line with an arrow on the end, **not** what is shown in the drawing above. The symbol shown is a varistor as 3 of us have pointed out (see the link I posted).

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks a lot for pointing this out...its a big mistake i did here....having cold ...;)

Comment: V.D.R. (Voltage dependent resistor)

Answer (score 5):

Doing a google search of "Resistor Symbol" and then looking at images, I came across this.

http://www.electroniq.net/electronic-tutorials/resistor-types-symbols-parameters.html

> [image]

According to the site, its a varistor tolerated symbol.

> a: resistor , general symbol
>
> b: resistor , tolerated symbol
>
> c: resistor , un-standard  symbol
>
> d: resistor with variable resistance
>
> e: resistor with mobile contact
>
> f: resistor with mobile contact and  stop position
>
> g: potentiometer with mobile contact
>
> h: potentiometer with mobile contact, general symbol
>
> i: potentiometer with preset adjustment
>
> j: two plugs resistor
>
> k: shunt resistor
>
> l: thermal resistor
>
> m: thermistor general symbol
>
> n: thermistor tolerated symbol
>
> o: varistor general symbol
>
> p: varistor tolerated symbol

Comment: I'd seen c) used for memristors (perhaps erroneously.)

Comment: I have seen c) used for resistive heaters.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use oficial symbols and not whatever gather from web.

Official Varistor symbol according to  the IEEE "Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams" (IEEE std 315-1975) is the follow:

[image]
Please refere to the follow standards if you want to communicate and distribute your diagram

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a varistor , a voltage dependent resistor